# JQuery Mobile radio buttons - multiple groups on one page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have multiple radio button groups on a single HTML page, and for each group, I want the first button to be checked.  When I set this in the HTML, the checked style is only applied to the button in the second group.

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="false" data-type="horizontal">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="A_AM_RadioButton" checked="checked"/>
        <label for="A_AM_RadioButton" id="A_AM_RadioButtonLabel">AM</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="A_PM_RadioButton"/>
        <label for="A_PM_RadioButton" id="A_PM_RadioButtonLabel">PM</label>
</fieldset>                             
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="false" data-type="horizontal">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="B_AM_RadioButton" checked="checked"/>
        <label for="B_AM_RadioButton" id="B_AM_RadioButtonLabel">AM</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="B_PM_RadioButton"/>
        <label for="B_PM_RadioButton" id="B_PM_RadioButtonLabel">PM</label>
</fieldset>
```

When I leaved the "checked" attribute out of the HTML and attempt to apply the attribute in my JS file as follows, I get the same result.

```
$("#A_AM_RadioButton").attr("checked",true);
$("#B_AM_RadioButton").attr("checked",true);
$("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio("refresh");
```

I can understand that JQuery Mobile does not want more than one button within a fieldset to be checked, but across fieldsets?

If there is anyone who might be able to tell me my mistake (or if what I am attempting is possible), I would appreciate it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing the names for each field set.

```
  <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="false" data-type="horizontal">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="A_AM_RadioButton" checked="checked"/>
        <label for="A_AM_RadioButton" id="A_AM_RadioButtonLabel">AM</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="A_PM_RadioButton"/>
        <label for="A_PM_RadioButton" id="A_PM_RadioButtonLabel">PM</label>
</fieldset>                             
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="false" data-type="horizontal">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-2" id="B_AM_RadioButton" checked="checked"/>
        <label for="B_AM_RadioButton" id="B_AM_RadioButtonLabel">AM</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-2" id="B_PM_RadioButton"/>
        <label for="B_PM_RadioButton" id="B_PM_RadioButtonLabel">PM</label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  My IDs are unique if you look closely, but I can understand your comment, they are similar enough to cause a readability problem.

Comment: Also you have the same names on each one. That is your main problem. If you have the same name for each group they will register as the same radio. Make the names unique for each group.

Comment: IDs here is not an issue, as long as you can select the first radio in each `controlgroup` using `.first()`.

Comment: Thank you!!  I was somehow blind to the names.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to find `data-role="controlgroup"` then for each group select the first `input[type=radio]`. Simultaneously, change its' `.prop` to `checked` and `refresh` it.

[Working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/sBn73/)

```
$(document).find('[data-role=controlgroup]').each(function() {
 $(this).find('input[type=radio]').first().prop('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh');
});
```